# Use `or` inside an `if` statment

Tags: php, conditional-statements

I don't know why this isn't working, in the database field `statuss`, the is `8`. And I am getting the output `You cannot do that!` from the bellow code:

```
if ( $o['statuss'] !== 1 || $o['statuss'] !== 8 ) {
  $ret['result_msg'] = 'You cannot do that!';
  die(json_encode($ret));
}
```

I already tried, but to no avail:

```
if ( ($o['statuss'] !== 1) || ($o['statuss'] !== 8) )
```

If I leave only `if ( $o['statuss'] !== 8 )` then all works like expected.

Comment: I tried with `!=` without success.

Comment: If value is 8, then the initial test `$o['statuss'] !== 1` is true, therefore `you cannot do that`.... did you mean `&&` rather than `||`?

Comment: @Guntis: Can you show me the output of `var_dump($o['statuss']);`?

Comment: @AmalMurali it`s integer.

Comment: @Guntis: see my answer below, for a solution using `in_array()` ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think it's working fine, but you're interpreting it wrong. Your value is **8**. So your expression is in fact:

```
if (8 !== 1 || 8 !== 8) {
    // ...
}
```

Your first expression is `true`, since 8 is **not equal** to 1, so you get: `You cannot do that!` as expected.

You want an **AND** expression (`&&`) because you want the error message to display when the value is not 1 **AND** not 8.

---

It seems you don't really understand well what's happening here, so let me explain it further.

Let's consider `$o['statuss'] !== 1` and `$o['statuss'] !== 8` seperately for all numbers between 1 and 8.

- `1 !== 1` => `false`, `1 !== 8` => `true`: Because `1 !== 8` you will see the message.
- `2 !== 1` => `true`, `2 !== 8` => `true`: Because `2 !== 1` you will see the message.
- `3 !== 1` => `true`, `3 !== 8` => `true`: Because `3 !== 1` you will see the message.
- `4 !== 1` => `true`, `4 !== 8` => `true`: Because `4 !== 1` you will see the message.
- `5 !== 1` => `true`, `5 !== 8` => `true`: Because `5 !== 1` you will see the message.
- `6 !== 1` => `true`, `6 !== 8` => `true`: Because `6 !== 1` you will see the message.
- `7 !== 1` => `true`, `7 !== 8` => `true`: Because `7 !== 1` you will see the message.
- `8 !== 1` => `true`, `8 !== 8` => `false`: Because `8 !== 1` you will see the message.

You see, you will **never** actually get into the `else` branch (or at least, skip the `if` branch).

Now, let's do the same if you use the **AND** operator:

- `1 !== 1` => `false`, `1 !== 8` => `true`: You won't see the message because not all conditions are `true`
- `2 !== 1` => `true`, `2 !== 8` => `true`: You will see the message because they're both `true`.
- `3 !== 1` => `true`, `3 !== 8` => `true`: You will see the message because they're both `true`.
- `4 !== 1` => `true`, `4 !== 8` => `true`: You will see the message because they're both `true`.
- `5 !== 1` => `true`, `5 !== 8` => `true`: You will see the message because they're both `true`.
- `6 !== 1` => `true`, `6 !== 8` => `true`: You will see the message because they're both `true`.
- `7 !== 1` => `true`, `7 !== 8` => `true`: You will see the message because they're both `true`.
- `8 !== 1` => `true`, `8 !== 8` => `false`: You won't see the message because not all conditions are `true`

Comment: I need to display message if statuss  not 1 or 8

Comment: @Guntis No, you're thinking wrong. Your code is not the same as "not 1 or 8", it's actually "not 1 or not 8", which has an entire different meaning. "not 1 or not 8" means that the message will always be displayed because it will fail when it's not 1 and if it is 1, then it isn't 8, so then it will also fail.

Answer (score 1):

You could do it with `in_array`

```
if ( !in_array($o['statuss'], array(1,8)) )
{
    $ret['result_msg'] = 'You cannot do that!';
    die(json_encode($ret));
}
```

Using `in_array` is saying, if `$o['statuss']` doesn't match either `1` or `8` then throw that error

Answer (score 0):

You're getting this directly from a database (I'm guessing), so `$o['statuss']` is most likely `string(8)` ant not `int(8)`.

When you use `!==`/`===` it's [strict comparison](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php) meaning the type HAS to be the same (`8 === '8'` is false - `8 == '8'` is not). Use `!=`/`==` instead to avoid this.

Alternatively, cast it as an int: `$o['statuss'] = (int)$o['statuss'];`

That said, `if ( $o['statuss'] !== 1 || $o['statuss'] !== 8 )` will **always** be true, as if it's 8, then it won't be 1, and if it's 1 then it won't be 8. If it's neither of them, then it'd be true too. Are you looking for the `&&` operator (meaning AND)?

Comment: statuss field in database is numeric (sql server 2005)

Answer (score 0):

In this statement: if ( $o['statuss'] !== 1 || $o['statuss'] !== 8 ) the first part evaluates as true ($o['statuss'] !== 1 = true). Therefore you get this message.

Solve it by turning the thing around:

```
if ( $o['statuss'] == 1 || $o['statuss'] == 8 ) 
{
// do your thing
}
else
{
// You cannot do this
}
```